# How to insert a string with dot symbol to excel cell using excel interop c#

Tags: c#, excel, sql-insert, oledb

I have a excel file without headers and I'm inserting there some text to specified cells using excel interop. Everything is fine as long as the string does not contain a dot symbol. Text is added to the cell but the application stops working and does not add any more texts. Below is my code.

```
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=0'", filenamepath);

using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
   cn.Open();
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO[sheet1$B3:B3] VALUES ('" + "Some string with dot." + "')", cn);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: `but the application stops working` Can you be more explicit?

Comment: It sounds like you might be getting an exception.  Please add a try/catch block to your code, and please update your post with the the error text if this is the case.

Comment: I don't get any exception. For example i want to insert  texts: first to B3, second to C8, third to E4. When first text contains a dot symbol the async method stops working 
and the other two texts are not added. I wrote wrongly that application stop working.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending the "string with dot" with a single quote `'`. This tells `Excel` to interpret the input as text, which is obviously required in your case. Also, note that a "comma" might give you the same problem, depending on the culture.

E.g.:

```cs
"INSERT INTO[sheet1$B3:B3] VALUES ('''" + "Some string with dot." + "')"
//                                  ^^
```

You can try it out in `Excel`. Without the `'` prefix, `Excel` will format any number-like text as a number.

Comment: Please encourage the use of parameters rather than encouraging SQL Injection.

Comment: You just did :) My intension was mostly to get a quick response whether this solves the issue or not. If it turns out to be correct, we can rewrite it using a parameterized query. Do you have some boilerplate code ready?